# Why these expressions are giving me output instead of compile error?

Tags: java, operators

I was giving a exam when i got this question What is the Output of following question

```
 public class ClassicQuestion {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int i = 25;
            double j = 95.0;
            System.out.println(j+=i);
            System.out.println(i+=j);

        }

}
```

And the option for answer was

1. compile time error
2. run time error
3. 120.0 145
4. 120.0 120

I don't know the correct answer but i thought correct answer would be one, but showed me incorrect answer? how can we assign one variable to different types of data types without conversion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Correct Answer 3.

Because according to

> > [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)
>
> Compound Assignment operators of the form `E1 op= E2` evalute to `E1
>   = (T) ((E1) op (E2))` where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once

so your 
`j+=i` changes to `j=(double)(j+i)`
and since now `j` value is `120.0`
next time i does `i+=j` it changes to
`i=(int)(i+j)` hence `145`

so OUTPUT is 
`120.0 145`

Comment: quote the JLS for better answer.